# Vimeo API doesn't find videos according to tags

Tags: express, vimeo, vimeo-api

We have an expressJS server that looks for videos according to their tags. Each of our videos has 2 tags that are able to uniquely identify the video.
Now, when we upload videos, the tags are set correctly, the video is optimised and everything looks okay. But when the server checks for videos with the tags of the video, Vimeo finds no videos at all. However, if we check for the tags themselves, Vimeo correctly identifies that there is a video connected to the tag. So for looking for videos with a tag the response is:

https://api.vimeo.com/tags/TAG_NAME/videos

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 25,
  "paging": {
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "first": "/tags/TAG_NAME/videos?page=1",
  "last": "/tags/TAG_NAME/videos?page=1"
  },
  "data": [ ]
}
```

But if we look for one of the tags the response is:

https://api.vimeo.com/tags/TAG_NAME

```
{
  "uri": "/tags/TAG_NAME",
  "name": "TAG_NAME",
  "tag": "TAG_NAME",
  "canonical": "tagname",
  "metadata": {
    "connections": {
      "videos": {
        "uri": "/tags/TAG_NAME/videos",
        "options": [ "GET" ],
        "total": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are 3 videos tagged with "TAG_NAME" and the tag api correctly finds three, the video api finds none. What is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The /tags endpoint only returns fully public videos - the correct endpoint for your personal videos is:

GET /me/videos?filter_tag=<tag_name>

You can see docs here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos

Comment: Yes, I copied the wrong endpoint, I indeed called /me/videos?filter_tag=<tag_name> but the videos didn't show up either way. It seems to be an issue with the vimeo servers tough, so nothing I could do.

Comment: Can you open a support ticket, https://vimeo.com/help/contact? We will need some account details to debug this with you.